# Removing command line switches

Tags: ruby, optparse

I use a library that defines its own switches and then passes along the `OptionParser` object to let me add mines.
However it adds switches I'd like to remove as they would confuse my users.

In essence, I'd like to undo this (without resorting in deleting the line of code, as it's a 3rd party):

```
opts.on("-p", "--port PORT", Integer, "Specify port", "(default: #{options[:port]})") do |v|
  options[:port] = v
end
```

I tried looking into the class's code but didn't find any `remove` mechanism.
So I figured I'd ask before hacking it via metaprogramming.

**Edit** - the metaprogramming way (vey hacky..):

```
class OptionParser
  attr_accessor :stack
end

...
  opts.stack[2].long.reject! { |k| k == "port" }
  opts.stack[2].short.reject! { |k| k == "p" }
...
```

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: @nTraum [dante](https://github.com/bazaarlabs/dante)

Answer (score 1):

While still not the most elegant of solutions, you could avoid re-opening the class by using the instance_variable_get method. In this case your code would become:

```
opts.instace_variable_get(:@stack)[2].long.reject! { |k| k == "port" }
opts.instace_variable_get(:@stack)[2].short.reject! { |k| k == "p" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted solution for the same problem and made a gem for it: https://github.com/KitaitiMakoto/optparse-off